# How to Listen For an Application Launch Event on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, applescript

I wrote an AppleScript to mount a bundled sparse disk image. I want this script to be executed exactly when Time Machine launches.

I can check if Time Machine is running with `on idle` statement,

```
on idle
    ....
    return <interval>
end idle
```

but I'm pretty sure, it isn't a robust way to do that.

IMO making an event trigger for `Application Launch` event would be a better approach.

I appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a LaunchAgent (see [Lingon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/files/)) to perform an action when a file is modified. Time Machine has some file somewhere that it modifies each time it starts.